# \thanks command error in MacTex2015

Tags: mactex, article

Since I updated to MacTeX 2015, I'm having some issues with the `article` class.  I narrowed the problem down to the `\thanks` command, but now I can't seem to remedy the error within this distribution.  Everything else in the document works fine, but when I include `\thanks` after my name, it creates an infinite loop.  If I keep the same preamble but compile with a previous distribution, everything works fine. Thoughts for a solution?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{setspace}\doublespacing
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{sectsty}
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm,amsfonts,thmtools}
\usepackage{booktabs,threeparttable,graphicx}
\usepackage[center,bf]{subfigure}
\usepackage[center,bf]{caption2}
\usepackage[nolists]{endfloat}
\newtheorem{thm}{Theorem}[section]
\declaretheorem{theorem} 
\declaretheoremstyle[headfont=\bf, headpunct={:}]{mystyle}
\declaretheorem[name={Hypothesis},style=mystyle,unnumbered]{Hypothesis}
\newtheorem{Proof}{Proof}
\newtheorem{Property}{Property}
\newtheorem{cor}[thm]{Corollary}
\newtheorem{lem}[thm]{Lemma}
\newtheorem{prop}[thm]{Proposition}
\theoremstyle{definition}
\newtheorem{defn}[thm]{Definition}
\theoremstyle{remark}
\newtheorem{rem}[thm]{Remark}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{color}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage[hyperfootnotes=false]{hyperref}
\hypersetup{colorlinks, citecolor=NavyBlue, linkcolor=Red, urlcolor=NavyBlue}
\bibpunct[,]{(}{)}{;}{a}{}{,} 
\def\citepos#1{\citeauthor{#1}'s (\citeyear{#1})}
\def\hlinewd#1{%
\noalign{\ifnum0=`}\fi\hrule \@height #1 %
\futurelet\reserved@a\@xhline}
\makeatother
\makeatletter

\singlespace \title{Clever Title\thanks{Thank you.}}

\author{Author\thanks{My institution.}}

\begin{document}

\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\vspace{.4in}
\begin{abstract}\noindent
Abstract of 150 words.
\end{abstract}
\clearpage \pagebreak
\pagestyle{plain}
\setcounter{page}{1} 
\doublespace

\section{Introduction}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please edit a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) into the question: `\thanks` works fine in a 'vanilla' document, so we'll need to narrow down what your issue is.

Comment: Put the `\thanks` *inside* `\author` and `\title`. Also you have an extra `\makeatletter` which should be removed.

Comment: Thanks, Alan.  I removed the extra \makeatletter and moved the \thanks to inside the \author and \title commands.  I forgot to edit that back when I was posting my code.  The error still occurs, though.  I receive the following message:  "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]."  When I switch to the 2012 distribution, no error is reported.

Comment: Your document compiles fine for me on TL 2014 and TL 2015. So I suspect that you have a local version of one of your packages somewhere.  Check through the log to see whether any of the packages are being loaded from `~/Library/texmf` instead of `/usr/local/texlive ...`  Also, if you examine the log file you will see a big warning about the `caption2` package (which is obsolete).

Comment: Thanks again, Alan.  Just to be clear, if there're any packages loading from ~/Library/texmf, I should move them to the /usr folder instead, correct?

Comment: @Scott No! If you have local files you should move them to your desktop or somewhere out of the way, and then try to recompile. The local files are likely old and outdated if you have them.

Comment: @Alan I've looked though the log and I have packages being loaded from ~/Library/texmf and /usr/local/texlive/2015.  My apologies for the multiple messages.  I haven't had any problems with any of this until a few days ago.

Comment: @scott It's no problem.  As a general rule you should remove *all* packages from `~/Library/texmf` that are part of the regular distribution and *only* keep truly local packages.  Your local texmf folder never gets updated, and that's why you encountered the problem.

Answer (score 2):

Change the lines

`\title{Clever Title}\thanks{Thank you.}
\author{Author}\thanks{My institution.}`

to

`\title{Clever Title\thanks{Thank you.}}
\author{Author\thanks{My institution.}}`

The thanks needs to be in the {}. Then, it should work.

Comment: Thank you.  That was my mistake when preparing my MWE.  The error still occurs in the 2015 distribution.  Something's creating a loop.  Here's the error message:  "TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [input stack size=5000]"

Answer (score 1):

Strange errors which arise when you update a distribution are often caused by incompatible packages. The most likely cause of this is having an older version of a package being loaded instead of the one from the new distribution.

TeX looks for files in the following order, and the first one it finds will be loaded. This means that local files will always override main distribution files if they are present in any one of the local directories.

```
local directory
TEXMFHOME = ~/Library/texmf (on a Mac) ~/texmf on most Linux systems
TEXMFLOCAL = /usr/local/texlive/texmf-local
TEXMFDIST = /usr/local/texlive/texmf-dist
```

Unless you really know what you are doing, you should generally *not* have local copies of packages that are part of the main distribution. To check this you can look at the log file.  When a package is loaded, its full path is given.  So for example in your document, compiled under TL 2015 you should see for the `setspace` package:

```
(/usr/local/texlive/2015/texmf-dist/tex/latex/setspace/setspace.sty)
```

If you have a local copy it will appear something like:

```
(/Users/<your-user-name>/Library/texmf/tex/latex/setspace.sty) [Mac]
(/Users/<your-user-name>/texmf/tex/latex/setspace.sty)         [Linux]
```

You should remove such packages if they are part of the regular TeX Live unless you really know why you need them to be local.